# binormal vector and curvature

Tags: vectors

We are learning about vector functions and their feature. we defined curvature and binormal vector for them for t or s (arc length) parametrization. Then our teacher ask two question. They are easy to understand but he wanted to prove them with calculation not by explanation.
1) find curvature of plane. (it's to hard for me to understand. I can't understand it because we use parametrization r(t) but not for a plane. I can't understand how to define that.)
2) binormal vector of a plane curve is constant.

Is it possible to help me?
I'm sorry for bad English. maybe I couldn't write information clearly for question. any improvement is acceptable.
Thanks.

Comment: A plane is *not* a curve. I find that request weird (this is differential geometry). Perhaps it was meant "a plane curve"?

Comment: Maybe but if it is, so there is no obvoious answer like zer or constant. But how about second one?

Comment: No, of course it is not true that *any* plane curve has zero or constant curvature...Do you know the binormal is always normal to the osculating plane of a curve? Since the curve is plane it means the osculating plane is always the same and thus also the binormal, in this case, is constant. It's hard to do anything more if you don't say what have you tried, what have you studied, what can you use...

Comment: Yes. I know about first sentence and I accept this. maybe first question is not complete. I will ask my teacher. But about second question, I know about osculating plane and I say, I accept your explanation about second question and it is true but our teacher wanted a mathematical prove for this and I can't do anything because of that. However thanks for information.